# Sqlite Query - Stuck on a Query returning a loop

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following relational schema.

```
stores(sid, name, phone, address)
categories(cat, name)
products(pid, name, unit, cat)
carries(sid, pid, qty, uprice)
customers(cid, name, address)
orders(oid, cid, odate, address)
olines(oid, sid, pid, qty, uprice)
deliveries(trackingno, oid, pickUpTime, dropOffTime)
```

Find cid of cutomers who have not ordered a product from the dairy category.

The following is my attempt, however I am lost as to why it is returning every CID multiple times

```
Select cid
from products, customers
where cat != 'dai';
```

Comment: You have a lot to learn about SQL, starting with proper explicit `JOIN` syntax and the use of table aliases and qualified column names.

Answer (score 2):

Dairy products:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE cat = 'dai';
```

Order lines with dairy products:

```
SELECT *
FROM olines
WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid
              FROM products
              WHERE cat = 'dai');
```

Orders with dairy products:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE oid IN (SELECT oid
              FROM olines
              WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid
                            FROM products
                            WHERE cat = 'dai'));
```

Customers without any such orders:

```
SELECT cid
FROM customers
WHERE cid NOT IN (SELECT cid
                  FROM orders
                  WHERE oid IN (SELECT oid
                                FROM olines
                                WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid
                                              FROM products
                                              WHERE cat = 'dai')));
```

---

If you are not allowed to use subqueries, you can join the three inner tables together instead, and then use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to find the `cid` values that do not appear in them:

```
SELECT cid
FROM customers

EXCEPT

SELECT cid
FROM orders
JOIN olines   USING (oid)
JOIN products USING (pid)
WHERE cat = 'dai';
```

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. I've been reading up on left join to see if its possible to not use nesting whatsoever.

Comment: If your homework does not allow nesting, then you should have mentioned it in the question.